# Makefile change directory and call git function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using a very basic makefile so far and there is the need to extend it.
Since I only know the most basic stuff about makefiles, I am seeking for help here.

---

The very top of my makefile defines a few values I use for different builds etc.
The important part here is the `EVALFILE`. It should link to a binary file and is mostly manually set when calling make like `make ... EVALFILE="example.bin"`

```
CC       = g++
SRC      = *.cpp syzygy/tbprobe.c
LIBS     = -pthread -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive
FOLDER   = bin/
ROOT     = ../
NAME     = Koivisto
EVALFILE = none
EXE      = $(ROOT)$(FOLDER)$(NAME)_$(MAJOR).$(MINOR)
MINOR    = 0
MAJOR    = 5
```

In case of no user-input for the `EVALFILE`, I like to get the file from the submodule in my git repository.

```
ifeq ($(EVALFILE),none)
    pwd:=$(shell pwd);                  \
    cd $(ROOT);                         \
    git submodule update --init;        \
    cd $(pwd);                          \ 
    EVALFILE := ../networks/default.net
endif
```

For this, I want to copy the pwd first to reset it later on. Then I change to the root of the repository, call my git submodule function to update the submodules. The submodule of interested here is `../networks/` which will contain a `default.net` which should be used as a binary eventually.

Unfortunately the code above seems to not work. When looking at the `networks/` folder after I execute the make command, there seems to be no files inside of it. Furthermore the `EVALFILE`is not being set this way. If I move  `EVALFILE := ../networks/default.net` to the top, it does get set but still nothing inside `networks/`.

I do assume I am not calling my `cd, git..` calls correctly.

I am very happy if someone could help me out here.

Comment: You can't move around in directories and set variables this way. Expressions in makefiles are either rules, which are run by a shell, or are "make" expressions, which are evaluated by make itself, not by a shell, unless you use a shell callout with `$(shell ...)`, which only lasts for the duration of the callout. Note that Git itself is not really relevant here, but when you want to run a Git command in some other directory, you can use `git -C <dir> command ...` as a short-cut.

Comment: You can only execute commands inside a rule or inside a call to $(shell). That said, I think your entire approach is wrong here.

Comment: So I do not really want to make this a rule. Is there a downside of using `$(shell ...)`?

Comment: `$(shell)` will run every time. It's better to take advantage of Make and use a pattern rule or something, so that it only evaluates things lazily. If absolutely necessary, include another makefile fragment.

Comment: So what I am looking for is a way to call a rule?

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually doing with `EVALFILE`, but it should probably be passed as a depedency to some other rule (either directly, or with a dummy prefix e.g. `evalfile-../networks/default.net` which would call an `evalfile-%` pattern rule). Making it a dependency gives you a place to execute the code that makes it actually exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing something with the contents of `$(EVALFILE)`. If it doesn't exist, you want to use a default file, and you might need to run a recipe to make that.

Assignments in the makefile aren't run if the variable's set on the command line.

So just do a plain assignment of the default value in the makefile, which you're expecting "is mostly manually set when calling `make`":

```
EVALFILE := ../networks/default.net
```

and supply a rule to make the default if it doesn't already exist:

```
../networks/default.net:
        git -C .. submodule update --init
```

(with a tab subbed in for leading whitespace since markdown eats tabs).

Then in recipes that need the evalfile, pass it in as a dependency:

```
mytest: this that $(EVALFILE)
```

and everything works.

Comment: I am not quiet sure if i understand the rule which is supposed to call the git command. When will it be executed and where should i place it?

Comment: You name the rule for the default evalfile. If that's needed and outdated or doesn't exist its recipe runs. So `mytest` in my example needs `$(EVALFILE)` which is whatever was given on the make command or if not there the default from earlier in the makefile. So if `mytest` is being made, `$(EVALFILE)` is checked and if it doesn't exist or is outdated its recipe is run, if it's the default file that recipe is the git command. Otherwise make will try to find whatever was passed in from the command line and make it if necessary.

Comment: Oh wow! That is pretty amazing that this works!! Thanks :)